# Outlook: How to set default picture style?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I always use the same picture style when pasting (not attaching) images into e-mails in Outlook 2007. Even with the Ribbon, setting this style every time is a 4-click process.

Is there anyway to set a picture style (Picture Tools | Format >> Picture Styles) as default on every paste, preferably without creating a macro?

Comment: macros are your friend ;--)

Comment: "...without creating a macro" It seems this may be the only route, but there's not a lot of clear documentation/example on Outlook (esp. 2007) programming.